# Autolayout hides Image for first start

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

i´m using autolayout in my Custom TableViewCell which is created with a xib file, it looks like this:

[image]

Everything works like expected and is shown correct, but i get a lot of Warning Messages while scrolling down the TableView:

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc3970d0 V:[UIImageView:0xc396fc0(75)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc3c1dc0 V:|-(10)-[UIImageView:0xc396fc0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0xc396f20 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc3c1fc0 V:[UIImageView:0xc3b7700]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0xc396f20 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc3c1ff0 V:[UIImageView:0xc396fc0]-(43)-[UIImageView:0xc3b7700]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc3bf8c0 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0xc396f20(126.5)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 

<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc3970d0 V:[UIImageView:0xc396fc0(75)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in    <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Especially the following Part is interesting i think:

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc3970d0 V:[UIImageView:0xc396fc0(75)]>
```

So the Problem is the Height of my UIImageview on the left Top??? I tried to delete the height and many other things, but absolutely noting worked for me....what can i do? I want a fixed size for my UIImageView on the Top Left...

**EDIT:**
Maybe the Problem could be that the bottom UIImageView is optional and sometimes its hidden, so that leads maybe to the warnings...

The important Part of my Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"NewsCell";


    GTNewsCustomCell *newsCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

    NSString *bottomImage = [[self.newsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"boardnoteImage"];

    if(bottomImage == (NSString *)[NSNull null] || bottomImage == nil || bottomImage.length == 0){

        newsCell.bottomImage.hidden = YES;
        newsCell.bottomImage.image = nil;
        newsCell.bottomConstraint.constant = 0.0f;

        [newsCell layoutIfNeeded];
    } else {

        newsCell.bottomConstraint.constant = 19.0f;
        newsCell.bottomImage.hidden = NO;
        [newsCell layoutIfNeeded];

        [newsCell.contentView addSubview:newsCell.boardNoteImage];

    }


    newsCell.titleLabel.text = [[self.newsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"title"];

    newsCell.messageText = [[self.newsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"previewMessage"];

    NSString *authorImg = [[self.newsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"objectImage"];


    return newsCell;
  }
```

**EDIT 2:**
I made some changes and the height calculation for the cell is now:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *bottomImage = [[self.newsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"boardnoteImage"];

//Check if the bottom Image exists
if(bottomImage == (NSString *)[NSNull null] || bottomImage == nil || bottomImage.length == 0){
//        if it not exists the cell should be smaller
    return 128.0f;
}
//if the image exists the size should be 250
return 250;

}
```

**EDIT: 3**

**FINALLY** it works now. I have two solutions. First one is to set the Cell Height to 148.0f, to be honest i have no idea why, maybe some strange insets from my UITextView?). And the secnd solution is to delete the bottom Constraint of the bottom Image and set a fix Height for the Bottom Image!

Comment: to have a working autolayout it's necessary to follow the blue guidelines in storyboard when you add or resize items. If it's not really mandatory, you can disable autolayout and use the classic springs/struts. They are simpler and easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i forgot to say that i´m using a xib file!

Comment: The same story for xib, use the blue guidelines. If you want to disable autolayout, you should uncheck it in palette (first inspector). Then, in size inspector you'll have the springs/struts available

Comment: But autolayout is the future so it seems i have to bang my head long enoug on the desk until it works :)

Comment: @CalinChitu The blue guidelines in Interface Builder are nothing to do with AutoLayout. They are purely there to help you place objects using the standard gaps defined in the Apple HIG. i.e. 20 points from the edge. 8 points between elements. etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current setup of constraints will give the bottom `UIImageView` a height of -1.5.

**Second rule of AutoLayout - You can't have negatives!**

You can see this from the error message.

From top to bottom (of the UITableViewCell) you have...

- A gap of 10.
- A height of 75.
- A gap of 43.
- **A variable height** (This is the big image view)
- A gap of 0.

This adds up to 128.

Now, you also have a total height of the cell from top to bottom of 126.5.

The only way to satisfy these is to set the variable height of the image view to -1.5. **THIS CAN'T BE DONE** It breaks the second rule of AutoLayout. And so it chooses a constraint that it thinks might help and removes it. Thus you probably get a image view height of 0 or something.

You need to change the constraints or make the cell height 128.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, that seems the Problem, i tried to change the cell height to 128, but now i get the same warning and it says: "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc576ec0 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0xc57c9c0(127.5)]>"

Comment: @Davis how did you change the cell height? The correct way to change the cell height is to change the returned value in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 128;
}

Comment: @Davis OK. What is the `newsCell.bottomConstraint` that you are changing? What is it constraining? Is this the height of the bottom image view? Or something else? Also, just try setting the height to 150 for me (just to see what happens).

Comment: @Davis actually this could be something to do with a default inset for the separator lines or something. i.e. you set the cell height to 128 but the cell.contentView height is reduced to fit tyne separator line in. Try a bigger value (129 should be fine).

Comment: See my Edit, i have to change the height calculatiuon a little bit! I tried it now with 150 and i get no warnings anymore....

Comment: @Davis see my second comment about the cell height and contentView height. I think you'll have to set it to 129 for this to work. Alternatively, do you absolutely need to have the constraints set the way you have them? Why not just remove the bottom gap (0) constraint and use a fixed height on the bottom image view instead?

Comment: With height 129 i get: "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc53ba70 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0xc5680e0(128.5)]>" I will try to delete the bottom constraint and use a fixed height

Comment: See my last Edit! Thank you very much, after 5h it finally works now without any warnings and problems :D

Comment: @Davis Haha :) happy to help. I'd recommend Ray Wenderlich's book (iOS7 by Tutorials) it has two whole chapters on AutoLayout amongst other things. Really worth getting.

Comment: Good idea, i will do this :)

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated your layout in a sample project and the only way I could reproduce your issue was by setting this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

If you're doing that, try removing it. I haven't had time to dig into the details to understand why this causes the layout to be over-constrained. But in general, I think a good rule of thumb is don't change this default value because the table view owns the layout of the cell itself. You only own the layout of the contents.

Comment: Thank you for your response, sadly i have never used that. Maybe the reason is the optional UIImageView at the Bottom (see my Edit)